# Ping only working one way

Tags: android, networking, ping

I've been using a server - client structure programmed in java back in the office for a while now and it worked perfectly. I'm currently trying to use it from home and it doesn't. Furthermore, I've noticed I can ping my phone from the computer, not so much the other way around. But the phone is able to ping the gateway. Anyone has any idea what might be happening?

Comment: That would be called a *firewall*.

Comment: But I've been able to do this before. It's the same machine and all.

Comment: At work, your phone is probably connected to wifi on the other side of the firewall.

Comment: Is it possible to make an exception for this kind of situation?

Comment: Sure -- there are many ways that your site network folks could provide access to your app. You need to talk with whoever is in charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @Ernest Friedman-Hill brought to my attention the issues might have to do with the firewall, silly me, I created a new incoming rule in the advanced settings section of the Windows firewall for the TCP port I'm using in the application. It all works like a charm now.